# How to build android.resource URIs for Platform resources

Tags: android

For a resource URI The format is:

"android.resource://[package]/[res id]"

[package] is your package name

[res id] is value of the resource ID, e.g. R.drawable.sample_1

However - what would I use for the package for a platform resource. For example, I would like the URI for the platform resource which is the favourited star.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package name for the platform resources is `"android"`, so the URI for e.g. the `star_big_on` Android platform drawable is `"android.resource://android/" + android.R.drawable.star_big_on`.

Here's the code for an Activity that displays that URI in an ImageView:

```
package com.example.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Setup an ImageView to display the resource URI with
        ImageView v = new ImageView(this);
        setContentView(v);

        // Set the URI to an Android platform resource
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://android/" + android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
        v.setImageURI(uri);
    }
}
```

Running the Activity will look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Works nicely on Anroid > 2.2; blank screen on Android 2.1 I guess that's just the point beyond where its supported.